# Convert 0.77777 into 77.8, i am using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, decimal

Convert 0.77777 into 77.8, I am using SQL Server, I have tried to use the `cast` function and also `round`. Please help me accomplish this conversion.

Thank you

Comment: Multiply by 100 and round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert or Cast would round as well

**Example**

```
Select Val1 = convert(decimal(10,1), 0.77777 *100 )
      ,Val2 = convert(decimal(10,1), 0.77725 *100 )
```

**Returns**

```
Val1    Val2
77.8    77.7
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT ROUND(0.77777 * 100, 1) AS RoundValue;